# Can't customize resolution 2560x1080 for ultrawide monitor in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, wayland

I'm facing some troubles in the first configuration for ultrawide monitor.
My laptop is a dell vostro 3501, core i5-1035G1 and monitor is a LG Ultrawide 25.7, model 26WQ500-B, 2560x1080, 75Hz

To create a modeline with the monitor's setup, I ran this command:

`cvt 2560 1080 75`

which displayed this:

```
2560x1080 74.94 Hz (CVT) hsync: 84.68 kHz; pclk: 294.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_75.00"  294.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1130 -hsync +vsync
```

I ran the next command to create a new modeline using xrandr:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_75.00"  294.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1130 -hsync +vsync
```

I added this modeline to the LG Monitor HDMI output, described as XWAYLAND0 (xrandr):

```
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "2560x1080_75.00"
```

And finally, set the default output for XWAYLAND0 (HDMI port):

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "2560x1080_75.00"
```

and it didn't work! A message was displayed further:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x556
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I really don't understand what's going on. I use the same LG Monitor in a core i5 8º generation laptop, with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed and it works perfectly, the 2560x1080 resolution. Just like I checked other discussions about Wayland and Xrandr compatibility or CVT can't gives the right parameters for modeline, maybe a customized modeline could work. I'd really aprecciate some help. Thank you, guys

Comment: Did you try installing drivers? Some people can't change the resolution because the monitor is not recognized. You can easily check in Settings > Displays, from there, you should be able to select your desired resolution, if it is greyed out, it is not recognized and needs drivers. Check both, your 22.04 and 20.04 installation.

Comment: Same exact issue here with a Dell monitor; no drivers available for Linux / KDE and still struggling why these common monitor doesn't have native support on mainstream desktop environments like KDE / Gnome.
If you get a valid solution please share it!

Comment: I just figured out short time before that my Dell laptop limited HDMI port and render till 42. So, the max resolution I could get was this way: 'cvt 2560 1080 42' and replacing 75 for 42, and that's It. Next time, I will check its HDMI limitation and I've just made my mind that was my last Dell laptop.